# Radiobutton on click event not working

Tags: android

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5kpl.png)    `

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Satisfied"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

         <com.example.rupertfernandes.itsforyou.progressutil.ProgressIndicator
                android:id="@+id/determinate_progress_indicator1"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Satisfied"
                android:textColor="#7CFC00"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/questiontext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Question of the Day"
                    android:textColor="#7CFC00"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/questiontextOne"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:text="Q-1. How are you feeling today ?"
                    android:textColor="#ff69b4"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/cell1"
                        layout="@layout/radiobutton"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/questiontextTwo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:text="Q-3. How is the day going on ?"
                    android:textColor="#ff69b4"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/cell1"
                        layout="@layout/radiobutton"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/questiontextThree"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:text="Q-4. How is the work going on ?"
                    android:textColor="#ff69b4"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/cell1"
                        layout="@layout/radiobutton"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/questiontextFour"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:text="Q-5. How is the night going on ?"
                    android:textColor="#ff69b4"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/cell1"
                        layout="@layout/radiobutton"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnsubmitwellbeing"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#7CFC00"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:text="Submit"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

below is the include code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroupWell"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/extremely_unsatisfied"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="extremely_unsatisfied"
            android:text="Extremely Unsatisfied"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/user_icon"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000" >
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/unsatisfied"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:button="@null"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/user_icon"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="unsatisfied"
            android:text="Unsatisfied"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000" >
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/neutral"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/user_icon"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Neutral"
            android:onClick="neutral"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000" >
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/satisfied"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/user_icon"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:button="@null"
            android:onClick="satisfied"
            android:text="Satisfied"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000" >
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/extremly_satisfied"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/user_icon"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="extremly unsatisfied"
            android:text="Extremely Satisfied"
            android:button="@null"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000" >
        </RadioButton>
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

`I have attached a file.
It has 5 radiobuttons in one row..and there are 5 such rows..the radiobuttons are inside a scroll view.
kindly help with xml file and the code as to how to check the radio buttons and also on click of submit the value in the circular progress bar should increase based on the user input in the radio buttons[the image is as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vxp9.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can't attach files here.

`RadioButton`s have an `OnCheckChangedLister` that does what you'd expect. Or you can call `isChecked()` to poll the value.

Comment: i have sent the xml..kindly help with it

Comment: To check a radio button, called `setChecked()`. Do you have a specific question about how to use a progress bar? If you, post that.